# White listing URLs with Java Spring Boot Security that used Firebaes Authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, firebase-authentication

I'm building a simple API using Java Spring Boot. This does basic CRUD operations. I want some of the paths to be authenticated and some to not be. In this example I want the `/habit/my` path to white listed while all the other paths to be secured. One of the other secure paths I'm working with is `/user`.

The issue I have is in this current implemenation. All request including the white listed once hits the filter and says its need to be authenticated. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. I could really use some help understanding where I might be going wrong. very new to working with Java and Spring Boot.

Here I've shared by AuthenticationFilter, Auth Provider, Model(to store authenticated user) and the security config.

AuthenticationFilter

```
public class FirebaseAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private static final String AUTH_HEADER = "Authorization";

    public FirebaseAuthenticationFilter() {
        super(request -> true);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        final String token = request.getHeader(AUTH_HEADER);
        if(token == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Auth Token in header - " + AUTH_HEADER);
        }
        try {
            FirebaseToken firebaseToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(token);
            AbstractAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new FirebaseAuthenticationToken(firebaseToken);
            return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authenticationToken);
        }
        catch (FirebaseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // This updates the SecurityContextHolder
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}
```

Authentication Provider

```
@Component
public class FirebaseAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        FirebaseAuthenticationToken firebaseAuthenticationToken = (FirebaseAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        firebaseAuthenticationToken.setAuthenticated(true);
        return firebaseAuthenticationToken;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return FirebaseAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}
```

AuthenticationToken(Model)

```
public class FirebaseAuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {

    private final FirebaseToken firebaseToken;

    public FirebaseAuthenticationToken(FirebaseToken firebaseToken)  {
        super(null);
        this.firebaseToken = firebaseToken;
        setAuthenticated(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return firebaseToken;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return firebaseToken.getEmail();
    }

    public String getAuthUid() {
        return firebaseToken.getUid();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return firebaseToken.getClaims();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean implies(Subject subject) {
        return super.implies(subject);
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    final private FirebaseAuthenticationProvider firebaseAuthenticationProvider;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        FirebaseAuthenticationFilter filter = new FirebaseAuthenticationFilter();
        //AuthenticationManager is responsible for invoking the authentication provider(s) to authenticate the user.
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class));

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authenticationProvider(firebaseAuthenticationProvider)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/habit/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .addFilterAt(filter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `FirebaseAuthenticationFilter` if there is no `Authorization` header, you can just let the `FilterChain` continue its processing:

```java
final String token = request.getHeader(AUTH_HEADER);
if(token == null) {
    return null;
}
```

It shouldn't be a problem since you configured the `AuthorizationFilter` (`authorizeHttpRequests()`) to permit access to `/api/v1/habit/**` and to require authentication for every other path.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I was looking for more of solid solution because I know it can be done but its just that there is something wrong in my code. If i do it this way all requests without a token will pass through, beating the whole purpose of having to authenticate.

Comment: The authorization should be handled by the `AuthorizationFilter`, what you are doing is authenticating the user. If the request passes this filter, it will stop on the `AuthorizationFilter` since unauthenticated users are not allowed to access the resource. This is the same behavior that Spring Security applies to its filters

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I think I'm starting to understand it. My concern is, correct me if I'm wrong here but isn't the whole idea of the ```.requestMatchers("/api/v1/habit/**").permitAll()``` to stop requests that matches that path to stop hitting the filter?

Comment: Also by simply returning null from the filter, it doesn't work. The request no longer goes to the service layer to actually perform the request when you return null.

Comment: `permitAll()` won't prevent the filter to be invoked, it means that that path doesn't require authorization. The `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` stops the filter chain if the `attemptAuthentication` returns null, in your case I think it would be better if you extended `AuthenticationFilter` instead